# Xpages xsp popup form + disable close button

Tags: javascript, xpages, popupwindow, maximize-window

I have a xsp form in Xpages, and this is called in a JS file as follows:

```
PopupWin = window.open('PopupWin1.xsp?iddoc='+id,'','width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+pt+',scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,left='+pl);
```

I want to disable (grey-out) the close button for this popup window. How to do so?

Comment: You want to disable the possibility to close browser window by user? Simply don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at help for `window.open` for the relevant browser. The popup window is not being managed by XPage functionality but is being opened as a normal browser window.

If you want to manage the opened window and it's being opened from an XPage, use the Dialog component from the Extension Library and manage using this answer [Non closable dialogbox from Extension Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920381/non-closable-dialogbox-from-extension-library).